# Startup screen on iPad Webapp

Tags: html, ipad, web-applications

I'm developing an iPad Webapp and I've a problem with the startup screen. I have read that the image would be a png file with a resolution of 1004*768px in portrait mod. That's the case for me.
The declaration of this image on startup is normally written like this : link href="startup.png" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" but it doesn't work fine...

Can somebody help me please ?

Comment: Can you give us your existing code? It could be an error you missed beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

Just figured out how to do this, and it's similar to the apple-touch-icon setup.

Here's my example:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="iPhonePortrait.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" sizes="768x1004" href="iPadPortait.png" />
```

Just set the "sizes" attribute to the specific width and height and mobile Safari should match it up correctly.